# docker-compose hostname to communicate between containers works with postgres but not app

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:11.0-alpine"
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - nuxt
  nuxt:
    image: node:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

I need `nuxt` service to communicate with `app`.

Within the `nuxt` service (`docker-compose run --rm --service-ports nuxt bash`), if I run

```
root@62cafc299e8a:/app# ping postgres 
PING postgres (172.18.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from avril_postgres_1.avril_default (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.283 ms
64 bytes from avril_postgres_1.avril_default (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.130 ms
64 bytes from avril_postgres_1.avril_default (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.103 ms
```

but if I do:

```
root@62cafc299e8a:/app# ping app     
ping: app: No address associated with hostname
```

Why does it work for `postgres` but not with `app`?

If I do `docker network inspect 4fcb63b4b1c9`, they appear to all be on the same network:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "myapp_default",
        "Id": "4fcb63b4b1c9fe37ebb26e9d4d22c359c9d5ed6153bd390b6f0b63ffeb0d5c37",
        "Created": "2019-05-16T16:46:27.820758377+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "53b726bdd01159b5f18e8dcb858e979e6e2f8ef68c62e049b824899a74b186c3": {
                "Name": "myapp_app_run_c82e91ca4ba0",
                "EndpointID": "b535b6ca855a5dea19060b2f7c1bd82247b94740d4699eff1c8669c5b0677f78",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "62cafc299e8a90fd39530bbe4a6af8b86098405e54e4c9e61128539ffd5ba928": {
                "Name": "myapp_nuxt_run_3fb01bb2f778",
                "EndpointID": "7eb8f5f8798baee4d65cbbfe5f0f5372790374b48f599f32490700198fa6d54c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "9dc1c848b2e347876292650c312e8aaf3f469f2efa96710fb50d033b797124b4": {
                "Name": "myapp_postgres_1",
                "EndpointID": "a925438ad5644c03731b7f7c926cff095709b2689fd5f404e9ac4e04c2fbc26a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "myapp",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.23.2"
        }
    }
]
```

So why is that? Also tried with aliases, without success. :(

Comment: why you should ping `app`? when you can ping `localhost` inside app container?

Comment: maybe that has something to do with run, did you try with up command ?

Comment: @Adiii he did that from nuxt

Comment: oh I thought he ping from the same container @Linpy.

Comment: @LinPy I guess this has something to do with `run` too, but that doesn't feel very deterministic ...

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I had to tweak your MCVE a little to make my test but it is working absolutely as expected: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/42ac6a9f1cdbdddb2292d175c57d8125

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `app` container is most likely not running. Its appearance in `docker network inspect` means that the container *exists* but it may be exited (i.e. is not running). You can check with `docker ps -a`, for example:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID  ...  STATUS   ...                           NAMES
fe908e014fdd       Exited (0) Less than a second ago      so_app_1
3b2ca418c051       Up 2 minutes                           so_postgres_1
```

- container `app` exists but is not running: you won't be able to ping it even if it exists in the network
- container `postgres` exists and is running: you will be able to ping it

It's probably due to the fact that `docker-compose run --rm --service-ports nuxt bash` **will only create and run the `nuxt` container, it won't run `app` nor `postgres`.** You are able to ping `postgres` because it was already running before you used `docker-compose run nuxt bash`

To be able to `ping` other containers after running `docker-compose run nuxt ...`, you should either:

- Have the other containers already running before (such as by using `docker-compose up -d`)
- Have the other containers `depends_on` the container you are trying to run, for example:

  ```
  nuxt:
    image: node:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    # this will ensure posgres and app are run as well when using docker-compose run
    depends_on:
      - app
      - nuxt
  ```

Even with that, your container may fail to start (or exit right after start) and you won't be able to ping it. Check with `docker ps -a` that it is running and `docker logs` to see why it may have exited.

Answer (score 0):

As @Pierre said, most probably your container is not running.

From below docker-compose from your question, it seems you are not doing anything in that container such as running a server or uwsgi to keep it alive.

```
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - nuxt
```

To keep it running in docker compose, add command directive like below.

```
  app:
    build: .
    command: tail -f /dev/null #trick to stop immediate exit and keep the container alive.
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - nuxt
```

It should be 'pingable' container now.

If you wish to run via `docker run`, use -t, which creates a psuedo-tty
`docker run -t -d <image> <command>`